# Brute force to generate possible permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 point groups, each of them contain 5 different 3D positions. My goal is to brut force all possible four permutations for each group without repeating the order and print them out as `(5x3)`array. E.g. for input data:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18
19,20,21
22,23,24
25,26,27
28,29,30
31,32,33
34,35,36
37,38,39
40,41,42
43,44,45
46,47,48
49,50,51
52,53,54
55,56, 57
58,59,60
```

I read the file:

```
def read_file(name):
with open(name, 'r') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip()
        cols = [float(i) for i in line.split(',')]
        data.append(cols)
    return np.array(data)
```

and reshape it to have `4x(5x3)` arrays to be brute-forced:

```
def main():
    filePath= 'C:/Users/retw/input.txt'

    data = read_file(filePath)
    print('data:', data, type(data), data.shape)

    reshapedData = data.reshape(4, 5, 3)
    print('reshapedData :', reshapedData, type(reshapedData), reshapedData.shape)
```

The current output looks like:

```
respahedData: [[[ 1.  2.  3.]
                [ 4.  5.  6.]
                [ 7.  8.  9.]
                [10. 11. 12.]
                [13. 14. 15.]]

                [[16. 17. 18.]
                 [19. 20. 21.]
                 [22. 23. 24.]
                 [25. 26. 27.]
                 [28. 29. 30.]]

                [[31. 32. 33.]
                 [34. 35. 36.]
                 [37. 38. 39.]
                 [40. 41. 42.]
                 [43. 44. 45.]]

                 [[46. 47. 48.]
                  [49. 50. 51.]
                  [52. 53. 54.]
                  [55. 56. 57.]
                  [58. 59. 60.]]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (4, 5, 3)
```

after brut force, the permutations as array or list should look like:

```
[[1,2,3]
 [16,17,18]
 [31,32,33]
 [46,47,48]] 

[[1,2,3]
 [19,20,21]
 [31,32,33]
 [46,47,48]]

[[1,2,3]
 [22,23,24]
 [31,32,33]
 [46,47,48]]
 etc,
```

until

```
 [[13,14,15]
 [28,29,30]
 [43,44,45]
 [58,59,60]]
```

**Edit**
For given two `4x3` arrays as input:

```
[[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]]

[7,8,9]
[10,11,12]]]
```

The output after brute force should be:

```
[[1,2,3]
[7,8,9]]

[[1,2,3]
[10,11,12]]

[[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]]

[[4,5,6]
[10,11,12]]
```

Comment: Your names and brackets notation for the values you're trying to create is very confusing. I have no idea what a "combination" is in this context, and you haven't explained it in any way I can understand, so I can't even begin to help you. If you're dealing with numpy arrays, show actual arrays, rather than pseudocode nonsense.

Comment: I edited my question to be simplify my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `numpy` and a generator that appears to work, generates the correct number of combos (625), and sequences them as you are looking for...

```
import numpy as np

f_in = 'data.csv'
data = []
with open(f_in, 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        l = line.strip()
        cols = [float(i) for i in line.split(',')]
        data.append(cols)

data = np.array(data).reshape((4,5,3))
#print(data)

def result_gen(data):
    odometer = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    roll_seq = [1, 2, 3, 0]  # the sequence of positions by which to roll the odometer
    expired = False
    while not expired:
        res = data[[0, 1, 2, 3], [odometer]]

        for i in roll_seq:
            if odometer[i] < 4:
                odometer[i] += 1
                break
            else:
                if i == 0:  # we have exhausted all combos
                    expired = True
                odometer[i] = 0 
        yield res

my_gen = result_gen(data)

a = list(my_gen)
print(len(a))
for t in a[:6]:
    print(t)
```

#### Yields:

```
625
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]]
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [19. 20. 21.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]]
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [22. 23. 24.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]]
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [25. 26. 27.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]]
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [28. 29. 30.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]]
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [34. 35. 36.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: How could I use dictionary instead of list for the permutations here, to know from which array row is the output generated? I want to know each row numbers for each `t`. E.g. `t(rowNumber[[1.  2.  3.], rowNumber[16. 17. 18.], rowNumber[31. 32. 33.], rowNumber[46. 47. 48.]])`

Comment: I gave you a working example above.  You could just create the dictionary response you want inside of the generator instead of returning a numpy array.

Comment: If I create the dictionary in the for loop  `res = dict(enumerate(data[roll_seq][i])) print("Dict:", res)` it gives me row numbers of the current reshaped array but does not say about from which row is that index created. For the first permutation from your solution the data should look like `[[data0, row0[ 1.  2.  3.]  data1, row0[16. 17. 18.]  data2, row0[31. 32. 33.]  data3, row0[46. 47. 48.]]]` Because the first `4x3` array is created from that reshaped array rows.  For 2nd iteration: `[[0, 0[ 1.  2.  3.]  1, 1[19. 20. 21.]  2, 0[31. 32. 33.]  3, 0[46. 47. 48.]]]`Thank you for the helps!

Comment: The row index in the generator is the `odometer`.  So you need to incorporate that in your dictionary construction, not an enumeration.  Try making a dictionary comprehension where the `key` is (data, row) and the `value` is the row...

Comment: use this statement: `res = { (d, row) : data[d, row] for (d, row) in enumerate(odometer)}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create something like this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,61).reshape(4,5,3)
print (a)
b = np.zeros((20,4,3))

for k in range(4):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(5):
            if i == k:
                b[5*k + j][i] = a[i][j]
            else:
                b[5*k + j][i] = a[i][0]

print (b)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 4.  5.  6.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 7.  8.  9.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[10. 11. 12.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[13. 14. 15.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [19. 20. 21.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [22. 23. 24.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [25. 26. 27.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [28. 29. 30.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [34. 35. 36.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [37. 38. 39.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [40. 41. 42.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [43. 44. 45.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [46. 47. 48.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [49. 50. 51.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [52. 53. 54.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [55. 56. 57.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [16. 17. 18.]
  [31. 32. 33.]
  [58. 59. 60.]]]
```

There are a total of 20 arrays of 4 x 3 I could get looping through this.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This solution creates permutations group by group. I would need permutations column wise. Please see my expected output. In the first iteration,  the first columns of all groups are taken, in the second, the first column of group 1, second column of group 2 and first columns of group 3 and 4. So it should continue in the next iterations

Comment: Yeah. I got it. I just need to tweak the code a bit. Will work on it after a few more meetings

Comment: @mystic.06, updated the answer. We have 80 rows to look at (or 20 x 4 x 3 arrays)

Comment: The permutation `[[[ 1.  2.  3.]   [ 4.  5.  6.]   [ 7.  8.  9.]   [10. 11. 12.]   [13. 14. 15.]]` is repeated several times. E.g. `[[ 4.  5.  6.]   [16. 17. 18.]   [31. 32. 33.]   [46. 47. 48.]]` is missing. I guess it does not do it iterative over all possible rows. Since we have 20 rows and 4 samples, the total number of perms should be 116280. But we eliminate the repeating, since [1,2,3] is the same as [3,2,1] or [2,3,1] etc, we should have then 116280/5! =969 different permutations. With the above answer, we have only 60 permutations. Yes we have 80x4x3 arrays to consider. –

Comment: I see the mistake. I am hardcoding it to just the top row. I will review this and see how to improve this. Interesting problem. I may have to see if numpy or python have inbuilt solutions.

Comment: I edited my question with an example input data as 2x(4x3) arrays and expected output. Thank you!